# MediaWiki template table conditional columns

Tags: html, css, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I have a template in my MediaWiki to display information in a tabular manner. The template looks like this (shortened for better overview):

```
{| align="center" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 400px"
| colspan="2" style="text-align: center; background-color: {{{Fon1}}}; color: {{{Fon2}}}"|'''Data'''
|-
| colspan="2" style="background-color: {{{Fon1}}}; color: {{{Fon2}}}"|<center>'''Overview'''</center>
|-
{{#if:{{{Soft Skills|}}}|
{{!}} '''Soft Skills'''
{{!}} {{{Soft Skills|}}}
}}
|-
{{#if:{{{Picture|}}}|
{{!}} {{{ Picture|}}}
|-
|}
```

They will be filled with an unordered list (`<ul><li>Skill One</li><li>Skill Two</li> ... </ul>`). There can sometimes be a lot, so I would like them to take two columns when they have more than5 of them.

I have looked at conditional tables, but haven't found anything that helped me. I have also searched no stackoverflow, but didn't find anything.

Can this somehow be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splitting lists into columns is fairly easy. There are several templates on Wikipedia that do this, the most popular being [Template:Div col](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Div_col), which uses CSS columns (the CSS is kept in [MediaWiki:Common.css](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css), which you would need to copy along with all of div col's subtemplates). You might also want to investigate the [other column templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Div_col#See_also) to see how they work.

The hard part is detecting whether the lists have five or more items in them. The template only sees the contents of the `{{{Soft Skills|}}}` parameter, so you would have to parse that somehow to find the number of items. This is tricky, because you can have both MediaWiki-style unordered lists:

```
* Item 1
* Item 2
* Item 3
```

As well as HTML-style lists:

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Also, the HTML-style lists can contain attributes and have inconsistent whitespace, etc.

Instead, you could restructure your template to accept several Soft Skills parameters, like `{{{Soft Skill 1}}}`, `{{{Soft Skill 2}}}`, `{{{Soft Skill 3}}}`, etc. Then you could do something like this:

```
{{#if: {{{Soft Skill 5|}}}
 | {{div col||10em}}
   {{unbulleted list
    |{{{Soft Skill 1|}}}
    |{{{Soft Skill 2|}}}
    |{{{Soft Skill 3|}}}
    |{{{Soft Skill 4|}}}
    |{{{Soft Skill 5|}}}
    |{{{Soft Skill 6|}}}
    |<!-- Add as many more parameters here as you think you will need... -->
   }}
   {{div col end}}
 | {{unbulleted list
    |{{{Soft Skill 1|}}}
    |{{{Soft Skill 2|}}}
    |{{{Soft Skill 3|}}}
    |{{{Soft Skill 4|}}}
   }}
}}
```

However, for this you need [Template:Unbulleted list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unbulleted_list), and of course, it is very ugly code.

To improve this, you can use the [Scribunto](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto) extension, and write the template in Lua. In fact, constructs like the one above were pretty much the reason that Scribunto was introduced to Wikimedia wikis. (And Template:Bulleted list requires Scribunto anyway.) With Scribunto you can just write a for loop to loop over all the Soft Skills parameters, rather than having to roll out the loop and only be able to iterate a finite number of times.

If you really want to stick with one `{{{Soft Skills}}}` parameter, then you can also try to use Scribunto to parse its content, but this will be difficult for the reasons I mentioned above, and because of other corner cases you might run into when parsing wikitext. Using parameters like `{{{Soft Skill 1}}}`, `{{{Soft Skill 2}}}`, etc. is the more reliable choice.

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive and well-informed answer :D